# Какую конфигурацию роутера выбрать?

Tags: сервер, сеть, железо, роутер

есть задача собрать сервер, поддерживающий подключение к wifi-адаптеру 800 мбит/c
На данный момент нашел такую мат.плату:
https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/3538c3096ffd3332/m...
И такой процессор к данной плате:
https://market.yandex.ru/product--protsessor-intel...
Но у меня есть определенные сомнения по поводу цены, возможно можно найти какую-то конфигурацию подешевле.
Подскажите пожалуйста варианты мат.плат с возможностью подключиться к роутеру и процессоров intel xeon к ним

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать один адекватный ответ, ибо он будет основан на мнениях, что вредит SO (сайту, который является базов интересных (не только вам) вопросов и ответов на них). Ну а так, ИМХО, сервер по WiFi, это извращение. Если что-то нестабильное делать, что не завязано на качестве сигнала, то может быть и да. WiFi вам добавить задержку, снизит скорость, и так далее. Не, если хотите, то советую для таких скоростей смотреть WiFi6, лучше отдельным адаптером, а не как встроенный в мать, ибо у матери антены бред. Но тут и роутер нужен с WiFi6, да.

Comment: А как организовать это, если не через роутер? Домашний кабель ethernet напрямую тыкать в материнку?

Comment: Кабель от провайдера <> Роутер (настроить на нем подключение) <> Компьютер. Все проводами.